# Shell logical not

Tags: shell, test

what is preferred between

```
if ! [ ... ]; then
```

and

```
if [ ! ... ]; then
```

actually they do the same result, is there a preferred syntax?
in the former syntax the evaluated not is the shell builtin, while in the latter the not is the `test` one, does it make any difference?

Comment: The shell will have `test`/`[`/`[[` builtin too. I'd say whatever makes your code easier to read

Comment: The first one looks more familiar to me because you use it with other commands than `test` too. I don't remember many use cases where I've used `!` as argument for `test`. The most often used expressions have their own opposite expression.

Answer (score 19):

### portability consideration.

The `!` keyword is POSIX but not Bourne while `!` has been supported by the `[`/`test` command from the start.

So `[ ! ... ]` is more portable than `! [ ... ]`.

Otherwise, as long as you don't use the deprecated `-o` and `-a` binary operators, they should be equivalent (if we put aside the parsing bugs in some old `test`/`[` implementations).

Actually, in the Bourne shell, to do

```
if ! cmd1; then
  cmd2
fi
```

You had to do:

```
if cmd1; then
  :
else
  cmd2
fi
```

(or use `cmd1 || cmd2`, though that could result in a different exit status in the end).

### interaction with `set -o errexit` / `set -e` / `ERR` trap

Outside of the condition part of `if`/`fi` statements, as noted by @mosvy, another difference between `[ ! ... ]` and `! [ ... ]` is that the latter will not cause the shell to exit when `! [ ... ]` returns false and the `errexit` option is on.

`!` applied to any pipeline cancels the effect of `errexit` as the shell considers the exit status of the pipeline is being used as a *condition*. The same applies for `failing-pipeline || cmd` or `failing-pipeline && cmd`...

While with `[ ! ... ]`, `!` is just a regular argument passed to the `[` command and in the end as far as the shell and `errexit` is concerned, it's just a `[` command returning with either a success or failure exit status.

```
$ sh -ec '[ ! a = a ]; echo here'; echo "$?"
1
$ sh -ec '! [ a = a ]; echo here'; echo "$?"
here
0
```

That doesn't apply when those commands are run as part of the condition section of `if`/`while`/`until` statements, as in there, `errexit` doesn't apply.

The same applies to the `ERR` trap of Korn-like shells:

```
$ ksh -c 'trap "echo OUCH" ERR; ! [ a = a ]'
$ ksh -c 'trap "echo OUCH" ERR; [ ! a = a ]'
OUCH
```

In practice that likely won't make a difference as `[` is almost always used as a condition, where `errexit` doesn't apply (whether it's in `if`/`while`/`until` statements or followed by `&&`/`||`).

Comment: I wasn't aware that `-o` and `-a` were deprecated inside single square brackets or with `test`, my `man test` doesn't say that they are. Are there alternatives (still using single square brackets or `test`)?

Comment: @gogoud, yes using `-o` and `-a` make for unreliable expressions, use `[ ... ] && [ ... ]`. See [the POSIX spec for the `test` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)

Comment: There's yet another difference -- it's how they interact with `set -e`. Compare `sh -ce '[ ! foo ]; echo yup` vs `sh -ce '! [ foo ]; echo yup`

Comment: @mosvy, good point, though it doesn't apply in the condition part in an `if` statement like in the OP's question. I'll add a note about it unless you want to add your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

`[ … ]` is equal to `test …`, so `! [ … ]` is equal to `! test …`. That means, you negate the result of the command `test`. In this case, `!` is a shell command.

From `info bash`, e.g. in section «pipelines»:

> If the reserved word `!' precedes the pipeline, the exit status is the logical negation of the exit status as described above.

On the other side, `[ ! … ]` means `test ! …`. That means, you negate an expression within test. See `!` in `man test`:

```
   ! EXPRESSION
          EXPRESSION is false
```

So it can have a different meaning. If you have complex expressions, the negation may only apply to a part.

It is up to you, what you prefere.